# match lines with leading 0s in date

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I am trying to grep strings in a file, which has filename and trying to extract that are older than 3 weeks old from the current date and i am having trouble with the leading 0s in the month or date format.

Here are the filenames and format that i am trying to extract the data from.

```
ABC_CTL_Xtra_05-12-2019.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_05-23-2020.csv
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_05-12-2019.csv
ABC_Supp_Rels_Xtra_05-26-2012.csv
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_06-26-2012.CSV
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_07-12-2019.csv
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_07-11-2019.csv
ABC_Supp_Rels_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_Race_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_07-10-2019.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_06-26-2012.sha256
ABC_CTL_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_CTL_Xtra_07-12-2019.csv
ABC_CTL_Xtra_07-30-2019.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_07-29-2012.sha256
```

```
cat abc.log | grep '^ABC_.*Xtra_*.*'
```

This basically gives me all the filenames. Could someone help me how do i filter the list to 3 weeks old files.

Comment: What problem are you having with the leading 0's?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -v today="$(date -d "today 0" +%s)" -F"[_.-]" '
    {ts = mktime($(NF-1) " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-3) " 00 00 00")}
    (today - ts >= 1814400) # 1814400s = 3 weeks
' file
```

Returns

```
ABC_Supp_Rels_Xtra_05-26-2012.csv
ABC_Full_Elig_Xtra_06-26-2012.CSV
ABC_Supp_Rels_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_Race_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_06-26-2012.sha256
ABC_CTL_Xtra_06-26-2012.csv
ABC_Supp_rep_Income_Xtra_07-29-2012.sha256
```

How does it work ?

`-v today="$(date -d "today 0" +%s)"` -> creates variable today = timestamp of today at midnight

`-F"[_.-]"`-> sets three different separator of columns, `-`, `_` or  `.`

`{ts = mktime($(NF-1) " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-3) " 00 00 00")}` this block is executed on each line of your file. It uses [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function  and creates a variable `ts` = timestamp of the date on the line. `$NF` is the last column , `$(NF-1)` the column before ....

`(today - ts >= 1814400){print}` -> this block is executed only when condition `(today - ts >= 1814400)` is reached i.e when the line has a date older than 3 weeks. `{print}` prints the line, this code is optional because it is the default [action](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Patterns-and-Actions.html).

Comment: This is perfect. Could you also let me know how can append static text before printing these matching filenames. sorry, if it is obvious but i am a unix newbie.

Comment: @ravi sure, do you need static text at first line before every filename or at the beginning of each line of each filename ?

Comment: I'll also add some explanations tomorrow so that you can understand and update the code

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation. You just saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):

```
sed 'h;s/.*_\(..\)-\(..\)-\(....\)\..*/\3-\1-\2/;s/.*/test $(($(date -d"-3 weeks" +%s)-$(date -d"&" +%s))) -gt 0 || echo NOK/e;/NOK/d;x' file
```

Format the date into `yyyymmss` and using `date` convert the date of the file to seconds from epoch. Subtract these times from the time 3 weeks back from today and if the answer is positive, delete these lines from the output.